# php artisan migrate:fresh出来ない

Tags: laravel

`php artisan migrate:fresh` が出来ません。
実行時下記エラーが出ます。
考えられる原因を教えてもらいたいです。

```
SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'user_id' (SQL: alter table `tasks` add `user_id` int not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージの通り、「tasks」テーブルにはすでに「user_id」というカラムがあるのに、さらに同じ名前のカラムを追加しようとしているマイグレーションがあり、失敗しているということだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。